# What is causing my default libraries to conflict with OpenGL extensions?

Tags: opengl, glfw, glew

So I'm currently following the tutorial for creating OpenGL programs on learnopengl.com,so I'm using GLFW, GLEW and the base library for OpenGL. However, when I go to build my code, I get a warning about how some of my default libraries "conflict with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library". So I went and disabled the appropriate defaults, and I get even more errors.

I'm trying to figure out, what other reason would there be that this error might be caused? From what I can tell, GLFW and GLEW should not experience this warning in the first place. I wouldn't have been too upset, since it compiles properly, however, when I add a third library in (one called soil, for adding images as textures), I get errors straight off the bat.

The libraries I used were from the official websites:

www.glfw.org/download.html (windows 32 bit binaries)

sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/1.13.0/ (the win32 .zip file)

I've seen people asking about this particular warning before, but the methods given to fixing it don't seem to apply to me :L

Edit: Here's the list of errors
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please specify the other errors that you have. It's hard to say what's wrong now.

Comment: sorry, added the error list. This is when I added in Soil. The ones that have always been there can be seen at the bottom

Comment: Can you add your linker input (where you specify glfw3.lib etc)? I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio 2013/2015.

Comment: @Honeybunch added

Comment: It works perfectly, I have these warnings too. I would like to get rid of them though, they're annoying

Comment: Maybe un-ticking the _"Inherit from parent or project defaults"_ and effectively linking with no-default libraries by setting the _"Ignore All Default Libraries"_ will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys, I messed up. I went back and checked to find that I had made a console application rather than an empty project, as was specified by the tutorial. Mostly likely the reason for it, or at least the first of many problems. Thanks for the help.